# Has Data ever gotten any software upgrades?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

Other than his emotion chip (which was more like adding a hardware peripheral), has Data ever had software upgrades?

I realize his programming was designed to learn and different areas of his positronic brain became "unlocked" (like dreaming) as he "evolved". But I don't think that really counts as a software (or firmware) upgrade.

Comment: I'm not sure anything qualifies as a "software upgrade" for something like Data. Data isn't just a computer program running on a serial processor; he's got a highly-parallelized brain much like ours. The only "software" he has is therefore things like memories and learned motor control. Specific sub-processors might be reconfigured, or he could upgrade to a newer model, but, like the emotion chip, those are more hardware than software. In fact, [he claimed](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Data#Human_development) that a pure software design would lose certain aspects of his personality.

Comment: How about in "Fistful of Datas," when tinkering by Geordi allowed Data to wirelessly communicate with ship systems?

Comment: Yes, the chip itself was hardware, but such hardware requires software (like drivers) and runs software itself. After all, the emotions were programs and sub-routines, remember?

Comment: What about when he meets Juliana Tainer, who tells him they had to add some modesty subroutines to get him to wear pants?  While I admit by definition a subroutine is not a full-system upgrade, it nonetheless adds a dimension to his functionality.  Would you say "Streaker Data" got a software upgrade into the Data of TNG?

Comment: @y0gapants: Chips can have software, but they certainly don't require any. And in the Star Trek universe, a "subroutine" isn't always software. Quite often, they're talking about a chunk of hardware that performs some logical function. Even the "software" in the EMH program is more closely related to a hardware neural network than the kind of code we typically generate nowadays. I don't think you can directly equate modern programming jargon with the terms used on the show. First, because Sci-Fi writers are typically clueless about the Sci, and second, because the tech just doesn't correlate.

Comment: Android never gets upgrades! *[DRUM STING]*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Data's software is positronic and hence *continually* updated by his experiences. Occasionally Data will encounter a situation that requires a more rapid enhancement of his basic software, at which point he artificially adds additional "subroutines" that he can call upon. You could argue that these represent a software upgrade.

We see this process most clearly in the episode "In Theory" where Data dumps the entire ship's catalogue of back-issues of Cosmo into his brain wholesale, resulting in him becoming the best/worst boyfriend of all time.

> **DATA:** *You are much more than that, Jenna. I have written a subroutine specifically for you -- a program within the program. I
>   have devoted a considerable share of my internal resources to its
>   development.* - <sub><sup>[TNG: In theory](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/199.txt)</sup></sub>

and in "Inheritance" where we learn that after trying (unsuccessfully) to use logical arguments to convince Data to wear clothing, Dr. Soong ultimately resorted to simply making him modest by *adding additional programming*.

> **JULIANA:** *We asked you to dress, but you felt it was unnecessary since you didn't need protection from the elements. We actually had to
>   write a modesty sub-routine to get you to keep your clothes on.* - <sub><sup>[TNG: Inheritance](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/262.txt)</sup></sub>